# How to show that the set of all non-decreasing functions $f:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \{ 0, 1\}$ is countable?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Given the set $A = \{f:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \{ 0,1 \} |$ if $n \geq m$ then $f(n) \geq f(m) \}$

How would I go about showing $A$ is countable?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you construct such functions?

Comment: Write down some examples of such functions and you'll see that this set is naturally countable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** If $f$ is not constant, show that there exists a smallest $k$ such that $f(k)=1$. Here smallest means $\forall  m< k$ we have $f(m)\neq 1$.

What can you say about $f$ then?

Comment: N.S.What an idea!

Comment: Question: Consider positive integers: Assume f_k countable , arrange in binary Cantor scheme: f_1=0011019...,I.e 1 to  0,  2 to 0,, 3 to 1,.....Proceed as in proving the Reals are not countable.Where do I go wrong?Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSzilas When you proceed as in the proof or reals being uncountable, the moment when you pick the first 1, you lost your freedom to construct a counterexample. Since the function is non-decreasing, everything which comes after must be 1. This means that after the first 1, you cannot make sure that the next digit is different of the corresponding digit in the next number.... Without the restriction "non-decreasing" the rgument would work.

Comment: @PeterSzilas To make it cristal clear: If $$f_1=00000111111.....\\f_2=01111111111.......$$, what are the first two digits you pick in the new number?

Comment: N.S.Thanks a lot.

Comment: N.S. Thank you for your patience , as is often the case with me, read only half the problem and ignored non decreasing which is crucial.:)

Answer (score 2):

We can draw the conclusion:

If the function isn't always $0$ and isn't always $1$, then it must be $0$ in the left and $1$ in the right. The point where the function changes its value has countable number of choices.